# C# Extension generic constraint or type coersion won't resolve for more complex type

Tags: c#, linq, generics, task, type-inference

Given the following extension:

```
    public static async Task<IEnumerable<TResult>> Select<TSource, TResult>(
        this Task<IEnumerable<TSource>> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
        => (await source).Select(selector);
```

I would expect type inference to accept any sub type of `IEnumerable<TResult>` but as I've discovered, this doesn't work.  It can't infer the types.

Then if I try and rewrite the type parameters like so:

```
    public static async Task<IEnumerable<TResult>> Select<T, TSource, TResult>(
        this Task<T> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
        where T: IEnumerable<TSource>
        => (await source).Select(selector);
```

The above recognizes the use of a task.Select(fn) but it complains that it cannot infer the types.

Any help here?  I really wanted this to work:

https://github.com/electricessence/Open.Linq.AsyncExtensions/blob/master/Open.Linq.AsyncExtensions/Extensions.cs#L3169-L3172

Comment: What is the difference between the two code snippets?

Comment: Did you try with "where T: IQueryable<TSource>" ? I had something similar when using selectors...

Comment: @Marco - Why `IQueryable<TSource>`?

Comment: @GiladGreen Sorry. :(  I screwed up.  Fixed it.

Comment: Still not sure the answer to this problem but I did find that Ix extensions (IAsyncEnumerable) does provide the interface.  The problem is, it doesn't do so in a way that is straight forward in relation to synchronous data.  I'm not trying to asynchronously query each entry, I just want to 'filter' results after the task is complete without having to await the task (awaiting happens downstream).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Open.Linq.AsyncExtensions/1.1.1

The solution I came up with to solve the type inference/specificity problems was to include a set of `.AsEnumerable()` extensions that cover common cases like `List<T>`, `T[]`, `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`, `Queue<T>`, etc.

As long as the signature is `Task<IEnumerable<T>>` the extensions work.